# Validation form with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is my submit form code. I want when clicking submit it will be validation form first before it is saved to the database. How can i make script validation form with ajax in function script bellow?

```
<script>
    function simpan_data() {
                var url;
                save_method == 'add';
                url = "<?php echo base_url();?>jurusan/getInsert";

                // ajax adding data to database
                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    type: "POST",
                    data: $('#form').serialize(),
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    success: function(data) {
                        //if success close modal and reload ajax table
                        $('#modal_form').modal('hide');
                        swal({
                                title: "Data telah disimpan",
                                type: "success",
                                timer: 1000,
                                showConfirmButton: false,
                            },
                            function() {
                                location.reload();
                            }
                        );
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert('Error adding / update data');
                    }
                });
            }
    </script>
```

Comment: `confirmButtonText: 'Yes, submit it!'
}).then(function() { '#modal_form')[0].submit() })`

Comment: This can be done with the Jquery Validation plugin. Look : [JQuery Validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/)